# Shiny server ProxyPass using apache

Tags: apache, shiny, reverse-proxy

My shiny server runs on my VPS without any issues (on Ubuntu, via Apache). So that's great. :) However, what I now try to achieve is the following (sorry for not using the correct terminology here, this is new for me):

Instead of sharing my apps via https://www.example.com:3838/appname, I would like to use https://www.example.com/appname (is this called port forwarding? aka 'getting rid of port 3838').

It is important to note that I do not want the shiny server to 'take over' my homepage as https://www.example.com serves my own personal site.

I tried the codeblock shared by [Chris Beeley](https://chrisbeeley.net/?p=1077) to be included in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf`, but that does not work. However, what does work to some degree is if I adjust the code as follows

**Original code**

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /shinyapps http://0.0.0.0:3838/shinyapps
ProxyPassReverse /shinyapps http://0.0.0.0:3838/shinyapps
ServerName localhost
```

**Adjusted code**

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /foo http://0.0.0.0:3838/foo
ProxyPassReverse /foo http://0.0.0.0:3838/foo
ServerName localhost
```

Yes, my app called foo can now be reached by www.example.com/foo; but this implies that I need to add the names of all my apps in this codeblock.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Also, I am sorry if this question turns out to be duplicate.

PS. All incoming connections to `http` are already redirected to `https`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood the way the URLs are structured. You need to point to

```
ProxyPass /foo http://0.0.0.0:3838/foo
```

As you have done, but foo is the name of the *directory* of apps.

So take all the application folders that you have, and put them inside foo.

Now the URL will be

```
https://example.org/foo/app1
https://example.org/foo/app2
```

Etc.

Comment: what if you want to display back the URL: `https://example.org/app1` how would you do this?

Comment: @road_to_quantdom untested, but ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:3838/ should work I think

Answer (score 2):

That should work:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /(.*)$ http://0.0.0.0:3838/$1
ProxyPassReverse /(.*)$ http://0.0.0.0:3838/$1
ServerName localhost
```

Check out this link: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/intro.html

Comment: Thank you Elvis, but this does not work, I get a 404-error now. I will have a look at manual too.